# Why does flexbox center element properly while positioning properties does not?

Tags: css

I am trying to center a div element. It seems in my code that all is right but the element is not being centered properly Where did I wrong? If i try to center it by using flexbox then it is centered properly. Where is the wrong of positioning property?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 39px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.cntr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: blue;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='cntr'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) instead of absolute positioning which will keep the document flow intact.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 39px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
}

.cntr {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='cntr'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can use flexible box. But I want to know why this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox
Here's the code
html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent{
  background: #000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;

}
.child{
  background: #ff0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Demo:
https://jsbin.com/duxakey/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I can use flexible box. But I want to know why this code is not working.

Comment: I think you want to raise the height check this demo https://jsbin.com/yamufiz/edit?html,css,output